# Prevenir bloqueo hilo UI

Tags: windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde añado distintas fechas en un panel.

Las fechas las obtengo por un método asíncrono y luego mediante un foreach añado las fechas a un layoutpanel

```
espera.visible=true;
 
var fechas = await SelectFechasTipoAsync(entity, idEntity);
 
foreach (var fecha in fechas)
   {
        panelLayoutFechas.Controls.Add(new CtrlFecha(fecha) { BackColor = blanco ? Color.White : SystemColors.Control });
   }
 
espera.visible=false;
```

El problema que tengo es que quiero mostrar una imagen animada mientras realiza la tarea y cuando llega al foreach se para la animacion puesto que bloquea el hilo ui.

Gracias por aticipado

Comment: Puede cambiar espera.visible adentro de SelectFechasTipoAsync?

Comment: El metodo selectFechaTipoAsync está en otra capa, tendría que pasarle le picturebox. Pero mientras se ejecuta ese método funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando llega al foreach que se bloquea.